# htaccess rewrite rule doesn't like a url encoded / (%2F)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

All rewrites have been working until I tried passing in a %2F (url encoded /)

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

URL that does not work:

- /divisions/other%2Fnon-merch/subdivisions

URLs that do work:

- /divisions/womans%27s%20shoes/subdivisions
- /divisions/some-thing/subdivisions
- /departments
- /anything/else/really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for Apache

You have to enable encoded slashes

AllowEncodedSlashes On